# ejabberd: process multiple packets with different namespaces in parallel

Tags: concurrency, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have added a custom namespace and xml packet structure to ejabberd. 
How can I scale ejabberd to process multiple packets (with different namespaces) to run on different queues in parallel and return the response to the client?
I remember observing the 'iqdisc' option in ejabberd, but it has been removed now.
Is there a way I can achieve this behavior? Am I missing something else here?

Any suggestions/pointers would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as what I have found online, ejabberd follows the one-process-per-connection idiom. There was no direct config option as such, so I had to manually spawn queues from the calling process and then route the packet back to the client.